# How to predict a Series sequence in a Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, prediction

I have a data that has three columns : user id, product id and date of purchase. I need to predict the next purchase date for User-Product pair.
[DataSet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9081r.png)
How can I make the prediction for this data frame?
I'm novice in machine learning and need your help for doing this.
Thanks.

[image: DataFrame]

I have calculated the intermediate days for each product-user pair, and I want to calculate the next date by predicting the next number in each sequence, which is the days between each purchase.
I split the "number days between" to `days test' and 'target' for training the model.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't know what should I do for modeling this problem. I tried to explain what I want to do. I have a dataset that contains user_id, product_id, and date and I want to predict next purchase date for every user-product pair. for now I want to predict the next number in number_days_between column.